# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty {\binom{z}{k}} $ for complex $z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

For what complex values of $z$ does the following sum converge?

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{z(z-1)\cdots(z-k+1)}{k!}} $$

And how would you prove it?

Mathematica seems to suggest the sum converges as long as $\Re(z) \ge 0$, regardless of the imaginary part.  Is that right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Isn't $2^z$ ?. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Felix: It is $2^z$ for the values of $z$ where it converges.  Actually, that was the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Wikepedia article [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series),
 which is about the series
$$ (1 + x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\alpha \choose k} x^k \tag{1}$$
if $\,x=1\,$ then $\,|x|=1\,$ and the convergence is

> If $\Re(\alpha)>0$, the series converges absolutely.
>
> If $-1<\Re(\alpha)\le 0$, the series converges
>     conditionally if $x\ne -1$ and diverges if $x=-1.$
>
> If $\Re(\alpha)\le -1$, the series diverges.

In the case in question
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty {z \choose k} \tag{2}$$
this translates to if $\Re(z)>0$ the convergence is
absolute, if $-1<\Re(z)\le 0$ the convergence is
conditional., and if $\Re(z)\le -1$ the series diverges.

The summary is that if $\Re(z)>-1$ the series converges, otherwise it doesn't. Notice, that unlike power series, binomial series such as $(2)$ do **not** have a radius of convergence.