# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{z(z+1)\cdots(z+(n-1))}{n!}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-functions

The series below converges to a familiar analytic function in some open half plane. Which half plane and which function?

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{z(z+1)\cdots(z+(n-1))}{n!}}=1+z+\frac12z(z+1)+\frac16z(z+1)(z+2)+\dots$$

In class we only cover that the power series converge in a circle of complex plane, so I do not have any clue about the series like this, any helpful hint or advice is welcome! Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\binom{z}{k}} $ for complex $z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266159/convergence-of-sum-k-0-infty-binomzk-for-complex-z)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576809/42969.

Comment: Well, that problem is z(z+1)(z+2)....., but my question is z(z-1)(z-2).....

Comment: @Cooper really? it seems to me, from the current question, that you are asking about $z(z+1)...$

Comment: Oh yeah, I am sorry. I mean my question is z+1 but that question is z-1

Comment: @Cooper: You are right, this one is slightly different, I have retracted my closing vote. However, the substitution $z = -\alpha$ shows that the series are closely related, and I assume that a similar approach as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1576969/42969 should work here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

note that, by using the notation of the [Rising and Falling Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
we can rewrite your sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{z\left( {z + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {z + n - 1} \right)} \over {n!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{z^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \over {n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\left( {z + n - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } } \over {n!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n + z - 1 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,\,n} \left( \matrix{
   - z \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)} \quad  \to   \cr 
  &  \to \quad \left( {1 - 1} \right)^{\, - \,z}  \cr} 
$$